# What happens if network is lost while rolling back transaction with TransactionScope in .Net

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have this following code:-

```
 using (var transactionScope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            bool IsCreated=false;
            context.CommandTimeout = 120;
            if(IsCreated)
              transactionScope.Complete();                             
        }
```

Now If transactionScope.Complete()  is not called, Transaction is rolled back once scope of using is Complete. However IF before this there is a network outage, how will this transaction be rolled back. It is rolled back as i tried removing the network cable but i dont understand how is it getting rolled back. According to my understanding if Transaction is not commited within the commandtimeout it is rolled back by sql server. Please validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CommandTimeout only impacts commands issued - not the overall transaction. DTC has a timeout (also available via some constructor overloads), but that is *mainly* intended for distributed deadlock scenarios.

In *this* scenario, I suspect it is more a case that the controller is keeping tabs on all the systems involved, and reporting failure if any of them fail to respond / keep in touch.